# How to set identity seed value using variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with columns `id, items`:

```
 ID    Items
----------------
 1      mc3
 2      mc2
 3      mc1
```

I want to insert this data into a temp table but the order of items in descending i.e

```
 ID     Items
--------------
  1     mc1
  2     mc2
  3     mc3
```

but I can't take order by of these items. `items` column has duplicate values. I tried to use identity column but that was a terrible idea. I will show that query.

```
  DECLARE @totalNO INT = 0

  SET @totalNO = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tblmc)

  SELECT IDENTITY(INT, @totalNO, -1) RowIndex1, * 
  INTO #tempmcfordesc 
  FROM @tblmc.
```

but this query causes an error. Is there any other way? I can loop the table and insert but I just want to know is there any easy way for this. Please sort this out.

Comment: You can try using `ROW_NUMBER()`, but you will need at least one column on which you can sort. If that column has duplicates, then you will need an additional column for sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have create the temp table then use this :

```
INSERT INTO #temptable
SELECT Row_Number()
         OVER (
           ORDER BY ID DESC) AS ID,
       Items
FROM   yourtable
```

and if you haven't created the temp table then create it with data like this :

```
SELECT Row_Number()
         OVER (
           ORDER BY ID DESC) AS ID,
       Items
INTO   #temptable
FROM   yourtable
```